# Applying hist to a list of dataframes containing NA's

Tags: r, histogram, lapply

Another question regarding list syntax (I am slowly learning I think). I have data in the following simplified form:

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA)
b=c(6,7,8,9,10,NA,NA)
c=c(6,5,3,NA,NA,NA,NA)
d=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
A=data.frame(a,b,c,d)
B=data.frame(c,b,a,d)
C=data.frame(d,c,b,a)
mylist=list(A,B,C)
bins=c(0,2,4,6,8,10)
```

I would like to bin each column in the list of dataframes according to the bins defined and then return a mean number for each bin for each dataframe. I dont mind particulary what form the output is, a dataframe or a list of vectors. Thus in this example:

```
hist(a,bins, plot= FALSE)
hist(b,bins, plot= FALSE)
hist(c,bins, plot= FALSE)
```

give counts of

```
$counts
[1] 2 2 1 0 0
$counts
[1] 0 0 1 2 2
$counts
[1] 0 1 2 0 0
```

respectively.

I dont know how to do it but given that d contains only NA's I would like it to return:

```
$counts
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

(I guess turn each NA into 0).

Therefore the mean of A (which contains a,b,c,d) would be:

```
$counts
[1] 2 2 1 0 0 +
$counts
[1] 0 0 1 2 2 +
$counts
[1] 0 1 2 0 0 +
$counts
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 +

=   2 3 4 2 2 / 4

=   0.5 0.75 1 0.5 0.5
```

This would be my desired output for dataframe A. The final list of vectors would also include relevant vectors for B and C although as I said a dataframe of columns for each dataframe in the initial list would also be fine since the final step will be for me to plot these mean counts against the midpoint of the bin.

I hope my explanation is enough to give some idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Make `d` numeric: `d <- as.numeric(d)` and it should work.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for that. In the simpler case that I want to ignore columns in the list of dataframes that contain all NA's (such as d) how might I go about binning the data and obtaining a mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in my comment, making `d` numeric will solve the simple case you're troubleshooting. To get the means you want to calculate across the entire dataframe, use `apply` and then take some `rowMeans`:

```
rowMeans(apply(A,2,function(a) hist(a,bins,plot=FALSE)$counts))
#[1] 0.50 0.75 1.00 0.50 0.50
```

To do it for a list of dataframes, just nest it in an `lapply` (or `sapply`):

```
> lapply(mylist,function(X)
      rowMeans(apply(X,2,function(a) hist(a,bins,plot=FALSE)$counts)))
[[1]]
[1] 0.50 0.75 1.00 0.50 0.50

[[2]]
[1] 0.50 0.75 1.00 0.50 0.50

[[3]]
[1] 0.50 0.75 1.00 0.50 0.50
```

(Note: Apparently your dfs all produce the same output, so this looks like it's not working correctly but it actually is.)

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the answer however how might I go about applying this to mylist (a list which contains dataframes B and C as well as A)?

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I just couldnt work out the syntax to nest the hist command.